# Unable to install wine32: "unmet dependencies" that are actually met (Ubuntu 22.04)

Tags: ubuntu, apt, dependencies, wine

I have installed wine64 without issue, but I cannot install wine32. I have tried both the normal `sudo apt install wine32` and `sudo apt install -t jammy-backports wine32`, and both result in the following error message:

```
Some packages could not be installed. This may mean that you have
requested an impossible situation or if you are using the unstable
distribution that some required packages have not yet been created
or been moved out of Incoming.
The following information may help to resolve the situation:

The following packages have unmet dependencies:
 apt : Depends: adduser but it is not going to be installed
 coreutils : PreDepends: libselinux1 (>= 3.1~) but it is not going to be installed
 dpkg : PreDepends: libselinux1 (>= 3.1~) but it is not going to be installed
 findutils : PreDepends: libselinux1 (>= 3.1~) but it is not going to be installed
 grep : PreDepends: libpcre3 but it is not installable
 init : PreDepends: systemd-sysv
 login : PreDepends: libpam-runtime but it is not going to be installed
         PreDepends: libpam-modules but it is not going to be installed
 sed : PreDepends: libselinux1 (>= 3.1~) but it is not going to be installed
 shim-signed : Depends: grub-efi-amd64-signed (>= 1.187.2~) but it is not going to be installed or
                        grub-efi-arm64-signed (>= 1.187.2~) but it is not installable
               Depends: grub2-common (>= 2.04-1ubuntu24)
 tar : PreDepends: libselinux1 (>= 3.1~) but it is not going to be installed
 util-linux : PreDepends: libmount1 (>= 2.37.2) but it is not going to be installed
              PreDepends: libselinux1 (>= 3.1~) but it is not going to be installed
```

`dpkg -l | egrep "adduser|libselinux1|libpcre3|systemd-sysv|libpam-runtime|libpam-modules|grub-efi-amd64-signed|libmount1"` results in the following:

```
ii  adduser                                    3.118ubuntu5                                                         all          add and remove users and groups
ii  grub-efi-amd64-signed                      1.187.3~22.04.1+2.06-2ubuntu14.1                                     amd64        GRand Unified Bootloader, version 2 (EFI-AMD64 version, signed)
ii  libmount1:amd64                            2.37.2-4ubuntu3                                                      amd64        device mounting library
ii  libpam-modules:amd64                       1.4.0-11ubuntu2.3                                                    amd64        Pluggable Authentication Modules for PAM
ii  libpam-modules-bin                         1.4.0-11ubuntu2.3                                                    amd64        Pluggable Authentication Modules for PAM - helper binaries
ii  libpam-runtime                             1.4.0-11ubuntu2.3                                                    all          Runtime support for the PAM library
ii  libpcre3:amd64                             2:8.45-1+ubuntu20.04.1+deb.sury.org+1                                amd64        Perl 5 Compatible Regular Expression Library - runtime files
ii  libpcre3-dev:amd64                         2:8.45-1+ubuntu20.04.1+deb.sury.org+1                                amd64        Perl 5 Compatible Regular Expression Library - development files
ii  libpcre32-3:amd64                          2:8.45-1+ubuntu20.04.1+deb.sury.org+1                                amd64        Perl 5 Compatible Regular Expression Library - 32 bit runtime files
ii  libselinux1:amd64                          3.3-1build2                                                          amd64        SELinux runtime shared libraries
ii  libselinux1-dev:amd64                      3.3-1build2                                                          amd64        SELinux development headers
ii  systemd-sysv                               249.11-0ubuntu3.9                                                    amd64        system and service manager - SysV links
```

This "unmet dependencies" error occurs only when trying to install wine32, and it makes no sense considering that all these dependencies are actually installed. I have no idea what to do from here.

For context, I am running Ubuntu 22.04 after upgrading from 20.04.

Comment: https://wiki.debian.org/Multiarch/HOWTO

Comment: @A.B I already have i386 architecture installed according to `dpkg --print-foreign-architectures`, so I'm not sure what else I need to do here.

Comment: Does it make any difference if you explicitly mention the architecture? `sudo apt install wine32:i386` — the error messages might be clearer (*i.e.* indicate whether `apt` is trying to replace `amd64` packages with their `i386` equivalent).

Comment: @StephenKitt same error message whether I specify `:i386` or `:amd64`